# Android. Testing Wordpress-login success with Java.

Tags: java, android, wordpress

I am developing an Android application that is linked into a Wordpress site.  I am trying to give out users an authenticaton step that would require than to input their username and password into the app to authenticate the person has an account on the wordpress site.

I *think* I am logging in successfully to the site.  When I put the correct username and password my output steam prints a UTF-8 encoded, what looks to be, web address

`01-17 18:16:28.884: D/output(8231): redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fzoombella.crontab.se&log=curtis&pwd=password&wp-submit=Log+In`.

If I purposely put it in wrong it returns the HTML of an entire webpage, most likely wp-login.php's output.

My question is:  **How can I tell, through Java, that Wordpress has been successfully logged into?  Is there something in a header?**

I have tested response codes, but since the site redirects on failure instead of returning a 4## error, I get 200 no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me as if you are trying to communicate with the normal web page. Wordpress has an xml-rpc API for externals apps. Have a look at [the worpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) .

Comment: I looked at that but It seems to be a little more complicated than what I need.  I just need to test and see if they are a member of the website using a username and password that they provide.  They won't be writing blog posts or anything like that.